# How do I parse a particular tag and its value from string using java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to parse an HTML code by giving the website URL. I'm getting the HTML code as a string. How do I parse a particular tag and its value from this result string?

I have tried with `JSOUP` and it is working, but I can't use that.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("my website url").get(); 
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("meta");
System.out.println(newsHeadlines.attr("charset"));
```

**Is there any way in java to parse a string and get particular tags and its attribute values?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("your tag");
for(Element element : elements)
{
     System.out.println(element.text());
}
```